# Getting [Unknown process name] CGImageCreate: unsupported image width: 84492328

Tags: ios, swift, cgimage

When I'm trying to navigate from one screen to another screen i'm getting "[Unknown process name] CGImageCreate: unsupported image width: 84492328." in console. And then stucked for few seconds, after that Mac asking for force quit the Xcode and simulator. Please tell me why this is happening. I'm not calling any service or download in while navigating.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details. (1) The "destination" view... is it a root view of a different VC? (2) If so, how are you navigating? Via a segue? (3) What's in this VC? (4) More broadly, what are you trying to do? For me the bottom line is two views (or VCs) are not usually firing off `CGImageCreate` much less something with an "unsupported width". I'm thinking those details may matter.

Comment: Myself fixed the issue. I'm applying font icon to a button(which has a font of type font-icon only) in xib.. Now I'm trying to change the font programatically, that's why I got this warning in console.

Comment: I've never seen this error before. Since this site is all about good Q & A to help others with the same issue, don't be afraid to answer your own question - but with details that would be of help with other having the same error. Glad you were able to fix things!